# Handling document relationships with T[] instead of T using RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

RavenDB docs show how to deal with document relationships in this [sample](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships) using Includes.

```
public class Order
{
        public Product[] Items { get; set; }
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] Images { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public short Age { get; set; }
        public string HashedPassword { get; set; }
}
```

How would I deal with Includes or Live Projections if I don't want to include the customer using Includes/Live Projections but a list of products instead:

```
public class Order
{
        public string[] ItemIds { get; set; }
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, this should help. I blogged about it here:

http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2012/03/keeping-domain-model-pure-with-ravendb.html

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, thats what I've been looking for. However, how does this behave with regard to performance?

Comment: I don't have exact numbers, but it performs well. Because you're retrieving everything in one session, and thus only one trip to the DB, it's quick. I've been lucky enough that I don't need thousands of documents in sub-second time, but it's my understanding that Raven really shines in this area anyway. Wish I had hard numbers for you...